# Обработчики событий используемые в swing и fx

Tags: java

Запускают ли обработчики событий используемые в swing и fx отдельный поток?

Comment: Нет, не запускают.

Comment: Объясни тогда пж каким образом программа возвращается к предыдущему участку кода, а не выполняется линейно

Comment: При запуске оконной программы создаётся один [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) и очередь событий. Все происходящие с окном события добавляются в очередь, а в EDT крутится цикл, который событие из очереди достаёт, передаёт обработчику, ждёт завершения обработчика, достаёт следующее событие из очереди и т.д.